# Codeigniter - PHP - encode and decode session userdata before is store and when is returned

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, decode, encode

i would like to extend the Session.php library in Codeigniter.

I would like to use a `base64 encoded/decoded session values`.

> So basically i would like to encode globally all session data before
>   it is setted (session->set_userdata()) and then decode that when is
>   returned (session->userdata('item'))

is it possible?

I'm in trouble how do i fire the moment that the session data is gonna be setted and the moment when the data is gonna be returned?

I'm using the Codeigniter session DB and planning to write MY_Session.php library but can't go on, i'm blocked here:

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session{

}
```

any help appriciated, thanks

Comment: You simply need to override the appropriate method for writing/reading data to include you encoding.  I would wonder why the need for encoding as you are going to be adding some overhead to the process.

Comment: @MikeBrant cause i need to support multibytes strings inside, and the default lib crashes with them :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the session library's implementations of `session->set_userdata()` and `session->userdata()`.

```
class MY_Session extends CI_Session{
    public function set_userdata($data, $singleVar = NULL) {
        if(is_array($data)) {
            foreach($data as $key => &$value) {
                //Encode $value
            }
            parent::set_userdata($array);
        }
        else {
            //Encode $singleVar 
            parent::set_userdata($data, $singleVar);
        }
    }

    public function userdata($item) {
        $data = parent::userdata($item);
        //Decode $data
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Your new functions will be publically callable instead of the functions in the session class, and by calling `parent::` you can access the function in the Codeigniter library.

Comment: can you help me with flashdata too? so i canaccept your answer istantly

Comment: UNDERSTAND the logic and try to do it on your own. Be creative!

Comment: @bradbadbedbread I edited the answer to include a more comprehensive implementation of `set_userdata()` so that it will accept both an array and a key, value pair as to parameters. Flashdata support is virtually identical to the userdata implementation, just override the flashdata functions with the same logic and change the function names.

Comment: @BadWolf but ... $array is not setted !? can't understand why you using for() and not foreach() ?

Comment: @bradbadbedbread That was a typo on my part, my mistake. I just edited it to fix that.

Comment: @BadWolf i'm gonna accept your answer, just before can you tell me if this is ok too http://pastebin.com/i3QB7JGd i copied from the Session lib the main method adding the base64_econde(); can i go for this ?

Comment: @bradbadbedbread That code *should* work, if you add a call to `$this->current->sess_save();` at the end of the function. However it is less 'future-proof' if the Codeigniter session library implementation changes in a future update.